# Resonance vs. Resonation

Tags: word-choice

Fellow wordsmiths - when would you use the one noun over the other?

In the following sentence:

> Science seeks to classify nature; Emerson rather directs focus towards nature's emotional (resonance/resonation).

Dictionary.com does validate `resonation` as a word, though it is not referenced in other dictionaries.

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody uses *resonation*. [See Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=resonance%2C+resonation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresonance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresonation%3B%2Cc0) So unless you're talking technical jargon which has a term that is *resonation* and not *resonance*, don't use *resonation*.

Comment: I wasn't convinced ***resonation*** was even a valid word (my Google Chrome spell checker doesn't like it either). But checking OED I get the impression it's a highly domain-specific usage within acoustics/vocal coaching/etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: that was also my impression after checking the hits for *resonation* in Google books. (But of course, the OED is more trustworthy.)

Comment: Fantastic! Appreciate the wonderful replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resonation is a technical term related to voice production.
https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GVeGnVinMa0C&pg=PA271&dq=%22resonation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G7OZVZKGMMXxUq_QgYgH&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22resonation%22&f=false

Comment: In particular, Emerson was not talking about that.

Answer (score 0):

[Some of this is just rationalization, and some speculation, as the word 'Resonation' does not appear to exist in all dictionaries]

A 'Resonation' (noun) is an individual instance of the action (verb) 'Resonate' (or, in combination with the verb 'to be', e.g., 'is Resonating', or 'will Resonate').

'Resonance' (noun) could also be used to substitute for 'Resonation' (and is probably a far more commonly used word).

However, 'Resonance' also refers to a property (e.g., having 'Resonance' is having the ability to 'Resonate'), or as a modifier (e.g., 'Resonance frequency'), whereas 'Resonation' would more be properly used as a noun of single instance of 'Resonance' or 'Resonating'.

So, I can see 'Resonation' used as a more technical, or specific term.

Examples:

1.) The last resonation of the C4 note, as performed by the lead singer of the band, was particularly powerful.

2.) When the next resonation of the oscillator circuit occurs, notate the (resonance) frequency in hertz.

Comment: Yes, I'd say that 'resonation' is more 'actual instance-' orientated, 'resonance' more property-orientated. This is nigh on impossible to find support for in dictionaries say, which tend to merely add the corresponding noun-form after the blurb on the verb. But add a couple of dictionaries which include the word, and I'll upvote.

Comment: Maybe a technical dictionary or reference has something?  I'm still looking... but I'm not going to lose sleep if I don't find anything.